# Losing R-Markdown title when automating knitting

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to automate the creation of a bunch of Rmd files that I have been tediously knitting manually with R-Studio - using the "Knit HTML" button that is enabled when you edit an Rmd file. However if I use the `knit2html` command from a script, it loses the title. This is apparently explained as by design in this post:

[Title not showing on R Markdown with knitr when rendering markdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852587/title-not-showing-on-r-markdown-with-knitr-when-rendering-markdown-file)

However it does not explain how R-Studio manages to generate the title in the html files it produces - it must be possible somehow, right? I have been trying with this `test.Rmd` R-markdown.

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Joe Programmer"
date: "Thursday, 10 June 2015"
output: html_document
---

Just read the instructions.
```

And getting this when I use the Knit HTML button below

[image]

But this when I knit from the console with knit2html()

[image]

How can I get my code to work the way R-Studio does?

Comment: As answered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/29518223/559676, knit2html() is for R Markdown v1 only. Your question looks different, but is essentially the same issue as that one.

Comment: I would not say that is exactly a duplicate, but it might be a help.

Comment: The answer supplied there (using rmarkdown::render()) does not work since it does not process the markdown. So no it is not really a solution to at this point although it might give me some additional ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate "does not work"? These three words are very commonly used, but they are really vague.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clearly expressed. "Using markdown::render() .... does not process the markdown". To make it even more clear, it does not process the markdown => it does not make the substitution => the titles do not appear => it is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio answers that [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552186-Customizing-Markdown-Rendering). You can see the template they use at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/038a31f8263f7bfe1b6c), and if you look at the markdown generation pane you'll see that eventually a wicked long `pandoc` call is made:

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc forso.utf8.md 
  --to html 
  --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures 
  --output forso.html 
  --smart 
  --email-obfuscation none 
  --self-contained 
  --standalone 
  --section-divs 
  --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html 
  --variable 'theme:bootstrap' 
  --include-in-header /var/folders/2d/r3dsy9j17lqcctq5k0hmmg040000gn/T//RtmptThd32/rmarkdown-str16cec488b85bd.html 
  --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' 
  --no-highlight 
  --variable highlightjs=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight
```

Dig into that similar output on your own system to see what else you need to pass to your own custom renderer to get the desired output.

Comment: Huh. Way more complicated that I expected. Will put some time aside to look into this.